# Keychain ARC Errors

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, automatic-ref-counting

I'm using the following code within XCode, building for iOS with ARC enabled. Why are these errors appearing?

[image]

Here's my code:

```
KeychainItemWrapper *keychainItem = [[KeychainItemWrapper alloc] initWithIdentifier:@"Test" accessGroup:nil];
[keychainItem setObject:@"Test" forKey:kSecAttrService];

[keychainItem setObject:password.text forKey:kSecValueData];
[keychainItem setObject:username.text forKey:kSecAttrAccount];
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're getting this because `kSecAttrAccount` and such aren't Obj-C types. Just place a `(__bridge id)` before each like

```
[keychainItem setObject:password.text forKey:(__bridge id)kSecValueData];
```

Comment: If it doesn't have an adverse effect on the .m file, you can switch off the ARC feature when compiling the .m file where there are (id) references. See this QA about [how to disable ARC on a per-file basis](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6646052/how-can-i-disable-arc-for-a-single-file-in-a-project).